# compiler warning left-hand comma c

Tags: c

Hello I am new to coding and I wrote this few lines to receive only lowercase
but my compiler only gives me this warning:

```
prog.c:12:15: error: left-hand operand of comma expression has no effect [-Werror=unused-value]
     b = ("%#x", a) + 32;
```

```
    #include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    
    char a;
    int b;
    
    printf("Bitte geben Sie einen Grossbuchstaben ein: ");
    scanf("%c", &a);
    
    b = ("%#x", a) + 32;
    
    
    printf("%c", b);
    
}
```

Comment: What do you want to do by `b = ("%#x", a) + 32;`?

Comment: You mean `b = tolower((unsigned char)a);`? (Add `#include <ctype.h>` to use `tolower()`)

Comment: i moved in the ascii chard to the lowercases by moving 32

Comment: Why not simply `b = a + 32;`? What do you think the `"%#x"` mean?

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: i tried it your way and it worked

Comment: the "%#x" is in hexadezimal

Answer (score 3):

As the message suggests, a *comma operator* is used in the part `("%#x", a)`.

This means

1. Evaluate the left-hand operand `"%#x"` and discard the result
2. Evaluate the right-hand operand `a` and make the result of evaluation to its value

In this case `"%#x"` does nothing, so you should simply remove that.

In other words, the line

```
    b = ("%#x", a) + 32;
```

should be

```
    b = a + 32;
```

Also here is a better code:

- Check the result of `scanf()`.
- Use `tolower()` to convert a character to lowercase.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ctypes.h>

int main(void)
{
    
    char a;
    int b;
    
    printf("Bitte geben Sie einen Grossbuchstaben ein: ");
    if (scanf("%c", &a) != 1)
    {
        fputs("read error\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }

    
    b = tolower((unsigned char)a);
    
    
    printf("%c", b);
    
}
```

The argument of `tolower` is casted to `unsigned char` for making sure that the argument is in the range of `unsigned char` (to avoid giving a negative number in environments where `char` is signed).